# How to write and edit later string on element string

Tags: c#, xml

my application generates xml file for restore/save form information. When click a button or etc... I want to edit it. Here is xml code:
My form creates this xml on load:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Labels>
  <label1>
    <Internal>
      <Text>Label Text</Text>
      <Name>label1</Name>
    </Internal>
  </label1>
</Labels>
```

I want to edit "Label Text" after clicking a button, is that possible?

Comment: Please share more info. What do you do with XML is it stored in a file, or kept in memory? If the later what is the object? Also if you share your case maybe there are better ways to do it. So please elaborate more

Comment: @Emad I will use it for save label text, textbox text and like this things. I just need to edit string between <Text> and </Text>, but i dont know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("controls.xml");

        XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("/Labels/label1/Internal/Text");
        foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
        {
            XmlAttribute DateAttribute = node.Attributes["Text"];
            node.InnerText = TextBox1.Text;
        }
        doc.Save("controls.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save a peace of information, using database or a better formatted XML would be better but, I try to just answer what you have asked. I will edit the answer if I get better information for what your actual goal is.

Let's assume that your XML is in a string called `xml`

If you know the old value in `<text />` tag you can do:

```
var newXml = xml.Replace("<Text>Old Value</Text>","<Text>New Value</Text>");
```

If you don't you can use

```
var start = xml.IndexOf("<Text>") + 6;
var end = xml.IndexOf("</Text>");
var oldValue = xml.SubString(start,end-start);
var newXml = xml.Replace($"<Text>{oldValue}</Text>","<Text>New Value</Text>");
```

Again, this is a simplistic answer and better ways are out there for whatever you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: **(-1)**  This is a ***terrible*** answer.  **Never parse XML via primitive string operations.**   There is no way you will cover all cases robustly.   Instead, use a ***real XML parser***, XSLT, or XPath.  Rather than  provide a misguided answer, you should have voted to close this question as too broad.

Comment: Btw I found better way